# JQuery - removeClass inactive

Tags: jquery

I have a function that moves buttons by adding css to the button using JQuery. My code looks like this

```js
function btnToggle() {
  $('.btnClass').addClass('active');
  if ($('.btnClass').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.btnClass').css('margin-right', '250px');
  } else {
    $('.btnClass').removeClass('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.btnClass {
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnClass">button 1</button>

<button onclick="btnToggle()">slide</button>
```

But `removeClass` doesn't work and the button can't go back to its original position

Comment: You just added the class, so the `if` condition will always be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the class unconditionally, so the `if` condition will always be true.

Instead of setting the style in the JavaScript, do that in the CSS. Then use `toggleClass()`.

```js
function btnToggle() {
  $('.btnClass').toggleClass('active');
}
```

```css
.btnClass {
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
}

.btnClass.active {
  margin-right: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnClass">button 1</button>

<button onclick="btnToggle()">slide</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function btnToggle() {
  if ($('.btnClass').hasClass('active')) {
    $('.btnClass').removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.btnClass').addClass('active');
  }
}
```

```css
.btnClass {
  background: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2em;
}

.active {
  margin-right: 250px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btnClass">button 1</button>

<button onclick="btnToggle()">slide</button>
```

Comment: your answers and @Barmar are both correct but answer of and Barmar is more detailed so I'll accept it. Thank a lot for answer, sir.